# Retrieve ResultSet using CallableStatement after executeBatch()

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to call stored procedure multiple times and use `executeBatch()` for this. Every call should return table with results, but I could not access this results. Next code works fine:

```
callableStatement.setString(1, "foo");
callableStatement.setString(2, "bar");
callableStatement.execute();
resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();
```

But next code doesn't work as expected:

```
for (String str : strings) {
    callableStatement.setString(1, str);
    callableStatement.setString(2, "bar");
    callableStatement.addBatch();
}
callableStatement.executeBatch();
resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet(); // returns null
```

I've already tried to call `callableStatement.getUpdateCount()` and `callableStatement.getMoreResults()` before extracting ResultSet, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Should your var be `callableStatement` or `cs`? I presume your actual code doesn't look like this? If so, that's your problem!

Comment: @wmorrison365, sure, it was a typo. It is not actual code, but it is enough to figure out difference between two approaches I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really the correct use of `#executeBatch`. The batch methods are for doing data manipulation rather that obtaining result data. That is, you can do batch inserts/ updates/ deletes but not reads. The result of `#executeBatch` is the update-count, indicating how many changes were made per batched operation

The intention is that you can improve performance by alleviating network overhead and database round-trip for alike data manipulation operations.

You don't typically execute queries on batch because different queries would result in different shaped `ResultSet`s (unless they were all for the same table with the same columns but a different query [but then why not just modify your query]).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which workarounds do you see in such situation? Do separate calls and read results after each?

Comment: @zvdh That is not a workaround, it is the only real solution.

Comment: Yes, use separate calls and read results after each... or, if the queries are all on the same table/ columns, can you modify the where clause to incorporate more results in the result (in your proc) or parameterise your proc to take an array or associative array to allow it to take multiple possible values? Consider if this may affect performance if we're talking about large ResultSets or if your indexes would need to modified.