# How to execute query of multiple statements as one?

Tags: java, sql

I came around an obstacle . The following statement does not execute because the `String query` contains multiple statements .

```
String query="create volatile table test1 as (etc . ); select TOP 10 * from test1; ";

        String driver = "com.xxx";
        String conUrl="jdbc:ccc";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,user,password);

        PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

The last line throws an error `Data definition not valid unless solitary`

It is very cumbersome to split my query into multiple `PreparedStatements`

Is there any other way to execute a query containing multiple statements as one ?

Comment: Whats wrong with executing them separately?

Comment: if a user types in a query `create ...where x='good ; ' and ..." ; select ... ;` How can i determine that the first query does not end after the word `good` . i need to write additional complex regex .

Comment: You can try `conn.createStatement().execute(sql)` which will sometimes accept multiple statements. But in general, if you use JDBC, you need to know where statements start and end.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JDBC batch processing (addBatch, executeBatch), which allows you to "stack" statements and send them all to the db engine to be executed at once.

Here a starting point: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

But you would still need to split it up into separate statements, and add them one at a time. [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

And, as @CHEBURASHKA has pointed out, it only returns the number of rows affected by each statement - no good if you want to ask for actual data from the tables.

Comment: +1 for attempt. However this is not correct . Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118698/retrieve-resultset-using-callablestatement-after-executebatch

Comment: You are right, depending upon what is in the SQL you are executing, and if there are results you need to see. I'll put it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be cumbersome, you've already done it by having your query containing the `;` character, which naturally terminates a SQL query.

So you have to do:

```
Stream.of(query.split(";")).forEach(sqlStatement -> System.out.println(sqlStatement))
```

Just replace the `println` for whatever mechanism you use to execute the sql query.