# How to execute multiple queries in teradata?

Tags: java, sql, teradata

For example a query : `create table ; select xxx  ; delete  ;`

How to execute it in one session ?

I saw one answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592224/how-to-get-resultset-from-executebatch) about mysql. The trick is to turn on `allow multiple queries`

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

---

**For teradata specifically,
what is the solution ?**

I tried

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:dsn?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

It is not properly working ?

Comment: I tried to edit this question , however StackOverflow for some reason did not allow me to edit . Thus, I opened a new question , a more detailed and precise version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605803/executing-multi-statement-query-in-one-session

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a Multi Statement Request (MSR). It's simply sending multiple SQL statements to the server sepatarated by semicolons.

But you can't mix DDL and DML in a single MSR because DDL must be immediately commited and a MSR is treated as a transaction (when running in a Teradata session).

Try two seperate requests:

```
create table ; 

select xxx ; delete ;
```

Comment: + 1 Thank you. i have done multiple statement queries in sql assistant : `create volatile table testTable as (select * from otherTable) with data  no primary index on commit preserve; select top 10 * from testTable ;` and it worked . I am pretty sure there is a way to do this from Java

Comment: The question migrated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605803/executing-multi-statement-query-in-one-session