# Executing multi - statement query in one session

Tags: java, teradata

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592383/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-in-teradata) and wanted to edit it , however StackOverflow for some reason did not allow me to edit . So here is the edited version

---

For example a query :

```
           create volatile table testTable as (select * from ... blah blah) ;
           select top 10 * from testTable  ;
           drop table testTable ;
```

It executes perfect in sql assistance as one session. I am sure it is possible to execute it in Java in one session.

**Goal : need to execute it in one session similar to `sql assistant` so that it is possible to refer to the volatile table in the subsequent select statement. Also the data from the select statement should be saved in the `ResultSet`**

---

*PS 
I saw one answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592224/how-to-get-resultset-from-executebatch) about mysql. The trick is to turn on `allow multiple queries` 
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
**For teradata specifically,
what is the solution ?**
I tried 
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:dsn?allowMultiQueries=true";*

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly failing?

Is there an error message "testtable doesn't exist"? Then your program closes the connection after each request.

Is the table empty when you do the SELECT? Then you forgot to add ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS to the CREATE.

Comment: This would really serve better as a comment.

Comment: Why? There are only two possible error causes and i provided answers to both :-)

Comment: If that's true, why not edit your answer to have the two possible use cases and solutions rather than 3 questions and two statements (lacking references or an actual solution)?